# .NET 8 MAUI and RadioButton: how to set the default value?

Tags: c#, maui

In my .NET 8 MAUI application, I want to customize the `RadioButton` to have a cool UI. So, I started to add this code to the *MainPage*

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <HorizontalStackLayout RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="MenuCategories" 
                           RadioButtonGroup.SelectedValue="{Binding Selected}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton
                    x:Name="radio"
                    Margin="0,0,15,0"
                    Content="{Binding .}"
                    GroupName="MenuCategories">
                    <RadioButton.ControlTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid RowDefinitions="30,4">
                                <Label x:Name="TextLabel" 
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </RadioButton.ControlTemplate>
                </RadioButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <BindableLayout.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>Hot Dishes</x:String>
                <x:String>Cold Dishes</x:String>
                <x:String>Soups</x:String>
                <x:String>Appetizers</x:String>
                <x:String>Desserts</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </BindableLayout.ItemsSource>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
    <HorizontalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="Your selection:" />
        <Label x:Name="labelSelection" Text="{Binding Selected}" />
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

The markup is displaying the `RadioButton` as I expected. The problem is the `SelectedValue`. I created a simple view model:

```
public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty] private string? _selected = "Hot Dishes";
}
```

In the core behind of the *MainPage*, I add

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
}
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't set the first value of the group to `Selected` value as expected and, also, if I click on a `RadioButton` it doesn't receive the selected value.

Comment: you need to bind the `Value` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jason said, you shoud bind the **Value** property for the RadioButton. Such as:

```
<BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <RadioButton
            x:Name="radio"
            Margin="0,0,15,0"
            Content="{Binding .}"
            Value="{Binding .}"
            GroupName="MenuCategories">
```

And then the selected value will show correctly. For more information, you can refer to the official document about [Responding to a property change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/radiobutton?view=net-maui-8.0#respond-to-a-property-change).